# Replace cell content 424 error Object Required

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to replace a cell's content based on another column.

My replace function is throwing a

> [424 error Object Required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-required-error-424?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1000424)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```
Public Sub OTherPN()
    CurrVal = ActiveCell.Value ' Takes the current value of the cell

    While CurrVal <> " " And NextVal <> " " 
        ' Checks for the condition if the next cell down is blank or
        '  does it have a command to STOP
        CurrVal = ActiveCell.Value
        MyLD = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        NextVal = ActiveCell.Value

        While NextVal = CurrVal
            ' This is throwing an error     
            MyLD.Replace What:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, _
              Replacement:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            NextVal = ActiveCell.Value
        Wend
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a watch on MyLD you will notice that it never has a value set because when assigning ranges to variables you need to use the set command

replace

```
MyLD = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells
```

with

```
Set myLD = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells
```

and you should have better luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, I always get confused when to use SET, fixed the issue I am having. As much as I want to upvote apparently I dont have enough reputation :(. But Thank you!! I really appreciate it!